# how to make one to many video streaming using serverless webrtc

Tags: php, html, video-streaming, webrtc

I'm doing one-to-many video calling in WebRtc using serverless WebRtc, have used adapter.js, serverles-webrtc.js, stun server.

When I initiate a group call,  Call will be initiated and single offer created for all group members and I capturing offer, after that group members getting the call when they are accepted the call didn't display video streaming of who initiated the group call in remote system and another side display remote streaming of only one group member video in all videos in local system(who initiated group call).